# Cell to textbox and back with only email addresses

Tags: email, textbox, userform

I have a spreadsheet where Column M contains a header in M1 and cells M2 - M22 contain email addresses that are later used to email the sheet as a .pdf.  I have found the attached formula to ensure the column only contains email addresses, but I'm trying to adapt it.  The user will click a command button to pull up a UserForm with 22 TextBoxes used to either change, add, or remove email addresses for the email to be sent, and then put the email addresses in the TextBoxes back into the cells on the worksheet. (The cells will be locked and can only be changed by the UserForm.) But I want to be able to either list the order of text boxes by inserting numbers 1-22 into the blank cells to show the user the order to use - to prevent blank cells - and then insert the TextBox values back into the cells only from TextBoxes with a valid email.  Any ideas how to adapt this code, or does anyone have a better idea?

````
    If Target.Column = 13 And Target.Value <> "" And Evaluate("COUNTIF(" & Target.Address & ",""*@*.*"")") <> 1 Then
        Target.ClearContents
        Target.Activate
        MsgBox "Please enter a valid email address."
    End If
End Sub```

Thank you in advance for any help!
````

Comment: My code 'Me.TextBox1.Text = CStr(ActiveSheet.Range("M1").Text)'. I will later insert whatever is in the TextBox  back into it's original cell, so I can validate the email address when I put it back, whatever is easiest.